# What does string length in octet mean in c language?

Tags: c, sockets

Writing a small socket program in c. The server expects clients to prepend message payload with the size of the message using a 32 bit unsigned integer that represents the length of message in octets. How do I get the size of the message in octets. The message is an XML string.

```
char xmlPong[] = "<upms><msg type=\"pong\"/></upms>";
unsigned int pongSize = strlen(xmlPong);

sprintf(str, "%4X", pongSize);
```

Comment: By [octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)) it means a data representation that uses 8-bit. Nowadays, we frequently also use byte to mean a 8-bit representation.

Comment: octets = bytes = characters (more or less). So you want the length of the string here. You might want to use the `strlen` function.

Comment: Octets may not equal characters in some encodings such as UTF-8. where several octets can combine into one character, so the length of the string and the size in octets aren't necessarily the same. But in your particular example, presuming you're on a system where `CHAR_BIT == 8`, they are the same.

Comment: Networking standardese tends to use the term "octet", which means a grouping of 8 bits, because the number of bits is very important in that context.  The words "byte", "character", and "char" do not convey that information as universally, for various reasons, but in practice, the `char`s and `unsigned char`s of a modern-day C implementation are near-certain to correspond to octets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Octets" simply means "8-bit bytes".  Therefore, `strlen(xmlPong)` is a valid way to calculate the length of your string in octets (not including the string's NUL terminator byte).

Comment: Thanks, just needed some confirmation!

Answer (score 2):

In some (rarely encountered) systems, not all bytes are 8 bits.  Most of those machines are dead now, but C must support them, or risk being non-portable.  To accommodate this, C leaves the exact details of "how many bits in a byte" as undefined.

So, in networking, you cannot have an "undefined" number of bits in your byte.  To correct this, networking code came up with the word `octect` which means "a number consisting of eight bits"

This means the length of your string is the same as the length of the string in bytes on 8 bit systems.  Don't forget any terminating white space.

Comment: It would be more precise to say that C does not mandate a specific number of bits per byte.  It does, however, mandate that `limits.h` define a macro `CHAR_BIT` that expands to the implementation's choice of number of bits per byte.  In this sense, the number of bits per byte is well defined, just not universally consistent.

Comment: In the USA they do too; but, it's a mistake.  There are some systems where the bytes are 12 bits long or longer.  The C spec is pretty clear.  A byte must have at least 8 bits, but the upper limit isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length and/or multi-byte character sets such as UTF-8 and UTF-16 mean that the length of something in "bytes" (octets) and "characters" can and will be different.

It's only 8-bit encodings (ASCII, ISO-Latin1, etc.) that they are the same.

Comment: This answer is true; but it doesn't even mention the word octet, and has little to do with why a new word octet is needed when we have the word byte.  Now if the question was "why do we have the word octet when we have the word character", it might have some relevance